# How to read an external SharePoint list using C#?

Tags: c#, search, sharepoint, external

I need to be able to use C# to search or query an external (online) SharePoint table. I know the link to the site and the name of the list. I don't have a SharePoint server on my local machine so I can't use local SharePoint API (so the Visual C# states), but I can read the SharePoint services from that site.

I'll add more information if needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Following is using **SharePoint CSOM 2010**.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
```

This is how I do it, but it could be not 100% accurate to your problem.

First, you obviously have to connect to your SharePoint site. I suggest using [MsOnlineClaimsHelper](https://github.com/chrisdee/Tools/blob/master/SharePoint/DocumentImporterForSharepoint/DIFSource/DIFS/DIFS/MsOnlineClaimsHelper.cs) for a starter.

I use this simple snippet to connect:

```
MsOnlineClaimsHelper claimsHelper = new MsOnlineClaimsHelper(site, user, password);
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(site);
context.ExecutingWebRequest += claimsHelper.clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest;
```

Then you just have to get your list by its name, the simpliest way would be to use a method like this one:

```
public Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List getList(string name)
{
    context.Load(context.Web.Lists);
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(name);
    context.Load(list);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    return list;
}
```